# \tcblisting ignores parskip?

Tags: tcolorbox, parskip

Using `tcblisting` I found that `\parskip` seems to be ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip\baselineskip

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcblisting}{%listing engine=minted, %listing only,
            verbatim ignore indention at end}
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
            1 & First point \\
            2 & Another point \\
        \end{tabular}
        
        Look at the previous 2 points.
    \end{tcblisting}
    
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        1 & First point \\
        2 & Another point \\
    \end{tabular}
        
    Look at the previous 2 points.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to also add parskip to tcblisting?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. The code indentation and the parskip are different topics.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I have remove the second question.

Comment: Thanks! Much better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the parskip for the tcolorbox like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip\baselineskip

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcblisting}{%listing engine=minted, %listing only,
            verbatim ignore indention at end,before lower={\parskip\baselineskip}}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    1 & First point \\
    2 & Another point \\
\end{tabular}

Look at the previous 2 points.
    \end{tcblisting}
    
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        1 & First point \\
        2 & Another point \\
    \end{tabular}
        
    Look at the previous 2 points.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. I cannot replicate the image you posted with the code you posted though: Why is your code not indeted but mine it?

Comment: @mrCarnivore I removed the indention in your code. In your question, your code is indented by 8 spaces. But as already commented, you should not mix different topics in a single question. This does not work well on a site which uses duplicates etc. to link similar questions.

Comment: But it also adds a parskip at the beginning of the lower part...

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yes, the lower part is a new paragraph. If you don't want this, add a negative `\vspace` or similar

Comment: But how to add any vspace in that without it showing up in the code section?

Comment: @mrCarnivore You can add it in `before lower={...}`. Your question could still benefit from an edit so it focuses only on one problem ...

Comment: @Is there also a possibility to add the `before low={...}` as a default option for all `tcblisting` in that document?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Have a look at the tcolorbox documentation for `\tcbset{...}`